# RubyMineでデータベースのテーブルが一部しか表示されない

Tags: rubymine

RubyMineでテーブルの内容を確認するためRailsのデータベースに接続しましたがテーブルの一つしか"アプリ名_development.public"に表示されません。
Synchronizeを試し、再起動してもやはり他のテーブルが表示されません。
他のプロジェクトではちゃんと全てのテーブルが表示されています。

誰か同じ状態となった方いますか？
もし対処法知っていましたら教えてもらえると助かります。

環境
RDBMS postgresql 9.4.5
RubyMine 7.1.4

Comment: RDBMSは何を使っていますか？MySQL? PostgreSQL? SQLite? RubyMine以外のツール（pgAdmin等）ではテーブルは全部見えていますか？見えているテーブルと見えていないテーブルに何か違いがないか、心当たりはありませんか？RubyMineのスクリーンショットやschema.rb、database.yml等を追記してもらうことは可能ですか？・・・等々、原因を推測するにはいろいろと情報が不足しているので、もっと詳しい情報を載せてもらうと助かります。ちなみに同じ現象に遭遇したことはありません。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。一度RubyMineとdatasorceの接続をやめて再接続しましたら無事表示されました。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決できました。
一度Data Sourcesで指定しているデータベースとの接続を取り消し、再度Data Sourcesでデータベース名を指定して接続をやり直すことでテーブル情報が最新のものに更新されました。